# What does "Murdru Kar" mean?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Let's first remember the scene where the Trollocs shout *"Murdru Kar"*:

> *(A Memory of Light)*
>
> Lan’s forces stop their retreat along the banks of the Mora. The ruins of Fal Dara and Fal Moran smolder on the horizon, destroyed by their own people to deny their resources to the Trollocs. They have fourteen channelers now to set against the enemy’s Dreadlords, led by the Asha’man Deepe, and the cavalry charges the Trollocs’ ranks for the first time in four days. The Trollocs concentrate on his banner, and Lan hears them shout **Murdru Kar, Murdru Kar, Murdru Kar** over and over as they attack. Lan sees his bannerman Andere fall, and he and Kaisel fight to his side. Lan dismounts and engages the Myrrdraal about to kill Andere, but sees a second Fade join in, and realizes it was a trap for him.

I've read the last book at least 3 times and each time I reach this scene, I cannot stop myself thinking of what this "Murdru Kar" mean.

I don't think this is a short sentence, it should be a special name because the two words start with capitalized letters.

This may be something about Lan or Malkier but I have no other clue.

Are there any knowledge about what "Murdru Kar" means in the Trolloc language, maybe in an interview with or a blog post of the author?

Comment: The "WoT companion" is no help; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z-UeCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT463&lpg=PT463&dq=Murdru+Kar&source=bl&ots=7ocTh0cyuG&sig=0LAVzetSQ7_Rpwe2cSGCZBkzpHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMp7zAhKzVAhXKPFAKHePWD1cQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=Murdru%20Kar&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It has no meaning that we have been made aware of.**

[*The Wheel of Time Companion*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765314614), written by Robert Jordan, has an entry for *Murdru Kar* that reads as follows:

> ***Murdru Kar***. Words uttered by Trollocs while fighting Lan in the Last Battle.
>   <sub>Source: Google Books result for *[The Wheel of Time Companion](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=z-UeCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT463&lpg=PT463&dq=Murdru%20Kar&source=bl&ots=7ocTh0cvlD&sig=IQJnsvGvLtDMAhWqRzZO6X6tLpg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Murdru%20Kar&f=false)*</sub>

An image of the entry:

[image]

Comment: Well, unfortunately we lost Robert Jordan in 2007 and I think these words are probably written by Branden Sanderson in _A Memory of Light_ then included in _The Wheel of Time Companion_'s later edition without the meaning. I was hoping for an explanation from Sanderson about this words in an interview or a blog post etc. Anyway, unless someone knows the meaning, I will check your answer as accepted.

Comment: @er-han, I hope someone does find the meaning, it's a really good question. There's a lot of knowledge about the Old Tongue but not much about Trolloc or Shadowspawn languages, it would be really nice to know more

Comment: You are exactly right

Comment: My mistake, TWoTC was first published _after_ AMoL. Still Sanderson may explain these words, though (I hope).

Answer (score -3):

Kill the king.  Murdru (murder) kar (king)

Look at the context.  Lan makes them super angry, and Lan is mentioned in the companion explanation.

"Lan's banner was a lodestone" = they knew damn well who they were up against.

Comment: How do you know this is the translation? Can you provide a source for this translation.

Comment: This might be true, but this is only a guess. Without any source, this is not an answer we can accept